# What's the difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Let's consider this:

```js
var obj = {a: 'tony'};
someFn(obj);
```

and this:

```js
someFn({a: 'tony'});
```

Since we know that 'obj' is a reference, "{a: 'tony'}" is an object literal, is there any difference between those two ways of passing an argument?

Comment: There's no difference. You're passing by reference both times.

Comment: JavaScript uses call-by-sharing: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language?rq=1)

Comment: The difference is that `obj` is defined outside scope of `someFn`

Answer (score 0):

> What's the difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference in JavaScript?

That there is no pass-by-reference in JavaScript, only pass-by-value.

> Since we know that 'obj' is a reference…

No, `obj` is a variable. And there are no references to variables that can be passed around. You always pass the value of the variable in a call like `someFn(obj)`.

However, the variable might *hold* an object reference as its value, and that is indeed the value that is passed here. Which will allow the function  `someFn` to mutate the *object* in place, but not assign to the variable `obj`.

Comment: Since you pass not the reference itself but a value that represents a copy of a reference, this evaluation strategy is sometimes called `pass-by-sharing`.

Comment: Yes, it's a copy of the reference value, so the object is shared.